# Refreshing progress bar in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, progress-bar

I have a Spring MVC project that contains a file converter. I made counting of progress in the main converter method - it displays percentage of conversion's progress in console now.

I would like to send those values to my JSP file and update my progress bar with them gradually, but I don't have any idea how to do that and because of that I can't even find any examples.

Comment: Give a try with **HttpHandler** to pass the values  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11655720/the-correct-way-to-pass-data-to-from-a-java-httphandler-class-for-java-httpserve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29). I think you can use AJAX to get progress from server.